# Connect Xiaomi Mi Box to Hotel Wi-fi

Tags: xiaomi, android-tv

I need to connect my Xioami Mi Box (Android TV) to my hotel wi-fi. The hotel wi-fi requires you to open a browser and sign in to an agreement page before it will connect a device. How can I get the mi box to do this? I have a fresh Mi Box and I need to perform initial setup.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve it by the help of multiple tools.
Here is how I solved it

What you need.

1. A mobile with active data connection.
2. A USB mouse (may be Bluetooth or WiFi mouse will also work)
3. A USB to transfer browser apk file to Mi Box(if you are running ES File explorer in your mobile or if your phone is detected as USB mass storage in Mi box, you don't need another USB.)

Here are the steps. During all these steps you can connect USB mouse and make use of it if needed and supported.

1. Connect Mi Box on your android mobile hotspot to access internet through your data connection. First create a hotspot on your mobile and then in Mi Box, go to "Settings => WiFi => Select your hotspot name and enter password to connect"
2. Select Google play store **in Mi Box** and download **ES File explorer** app. Mi Box is not having any file explorer(we need this to install a browser apk in Mi box). I think there is no alternative to this step.
3. Download any browser apk in your PC/mobile. I used MIUI 7 browser(find link provided at end).
   Search in google for browser apk file(chrome apk, firefox apk etc. somehow firefox didn't install, may be a bad download)
4. Transfer downloaded browser apk to Mi Box (if you can access and install from downloaded storage, you need not to copy it to Mi Box. Make use of ES file explorer both on mobile and Mi Box).

You may need a USB to transfer it(Copy to USB from PC/mobile, connect it on Mi Box, use installed ES file explorer to copy it on Mi box.

If you are running ES file explorer in your mobile, you can make use of options under Network tab of ES file explorer(LAN, FTP, and may be the best is Sender).

5. Open ES file explorer in Mi Box, Explore and Select copied browser APK file and chose install option. For this you should enable "Unknown sources to On" in Mi box. 
   To enable Unknown sources = On, Go to "Settings => Security & restrictions => Unknown sources"
6. Now we will switch back to hotel WiFi from hotspot. In Mi Box Go to "Settings => WiFi => connect to your hotel WiFi( select your hotel WiFi name). You can turn off your hotspot in mobile if needed.
7. After installing open the browser. The browser is not designed for Android TV so it will not be displayed in home screen.
   Find the browser under "Settings => Apps => Downloaded apps"
   Make use of your USB mouse and to select address bar. Once you select the address bar, On screen keyboard will be displayed. Enter the url or some search keywords to connect to your Hotel Wifi. Rest of the procedure is depending on your connection method.

Now your Mi Box is connected to internet and enjoy the shows.
Install Kodi and add addons for more shows.

If you are using MIUI browser apk, It may show some Chinese. Don't worry the language of app is in English. I always prefer desktop mode for MIUI browser. To set for desktop mode - Click on options button on extreme top right corner, select "Settings" from drop down menus, Scroll down and find "Advanced" menu, Scroll down and select "User agent string" to "Desktop".For all these you need a mouse.

[MIUI 7 Browser](http://en.miui.com/thread-198996-1-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. connect your  mouse  USB to the MI BOX
2. make sure it's connected and working i.e. move around your mouse where you can se that in the TV screen
3. connect to the hotel WIFI page, and enter the username and the password
4. move the mouse curser to the box where indicate to agree and T&C . Click yes , assuming you agree to them.
5. login, and you are all set

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used zank remote. First downloaded it with my own hotspot, after installation used with the wifi from hotel, they will find eachother before registration is done